# Comparing word with word in the txt file and method for homonym

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the program for checking if the two words entered by the user are homonym or not.

In the code chkFound method is for checking if the word is found in homs.txt file. And chkHoms is for cheking if it is homonym or not.

What should be the method for chkFound and chkHom ?

```
      String[] wArr = new String[50];
      String[] pArr = new String[50];
      String pcPathName="C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Comp";
      String fileName="homs.txt";
      readFile(fileName,wArr,pArr);// method loads array
      //readFile(fileName,wArr,pArr);
    //main control loop
      while(true) {
      //use input dialog to get 2 words from user
      String w1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter First word: ");
      String w2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Second word: ");
      //check each word if in dictionary
      int w1ix = chkFound(w1, wArr);
      boolean isFound1 =(w1ix>=0);
      System.out.println("\n"+w1 + " is found: " + isFound1);

      int w2ix = chkFound(w2, wArr);
      boolean isFound2 =(w2ix>=0);
      System.out.println("\n"+w2 + " is found: " + isFound2); 

      if (w1ix>=0 && w2ix>=0) msg = "\nboth words " + w1 + " and " + w2 + "are in the dictionary";
      else {msg = "one or more words not in dictionary: ";
         if (isFound1) msg += w1 +" "; //identify which words
         if (isFound2) msg += w2 +" ";}
      System.out.println(msg);
      boolean isHom = chkHom(w1ix, w2ix, pArr);
      }//end loop
   }//end main

public static void readFile(String xName, String[] wArr, String[] pArr) throws Exception {
      // create a file instance
      File fName=new File(xName);
      //create scanner for file
      Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("homs.txt"));
      //read data from file
      int i=0,siz=wArr.length;
      while(input.hasNext())  {
         String word=input.next();
         String pron=input.nextLine(); //clear cr/if
         wArr[i]=word;
         pArr[i]=pron;
         i++;
         if($DEBUG) System.out.println(i + spc + word + "|" + pron);
         if(i>=siz) { 
            if($DEBUG) System.out.println("array overflow");
            break;}
            }

          input.close();
          return;
          }//end Readfile 

   static int chkFound(String w1, String[] wArr) {
   return 0;
   }//end chkFound

   static boolean chkHom(int x1, int x2, String[] pArr) {
   return true;
   }//end chkHom
}//end class
```

The txt file contains two words in each line seperated by comma. These words are the pairs of homonyms. The txt file act as dictionary from which the words are compared.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snA4.jpg)

Comment: Imo, it is impossible to answer that without knowing the format and contents of the files.

Comment: added the description for the format and contents of the text file. Also added the reading code for the file.